# Using x and y coordinates with glTranslate

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Ive got a c++ programme thats run from my pc, it connects to my Android application on my phone and simultaneously  opens an image in OpenGL on my pc. At the moment the image in openGL is translated and zoomed in using keyboard buttons.  X and y coordinates are streamed from my android device to the terminal.

Is there a way to take these raw x and y values and use them to translate my image in OpenGL? Thus the user controls the images on the PC from the Android device. Im guessing the values will need to be scaled and normalized in some way?

I can supply my code or parts of it if it makes it clearer.

```
using namespace std;
#define USE_TOMS_OGL


class device_info {
    public:
    char            *name;

    vrpn_Analog_Remote  *ana;


};
const unsigned MAX_DEVICES = 2;

float translateX = 0.0;
float translateY = 0.0;
float translateZ = 1.0;
float imgScale = 0.8;
float panX = 0.125; 
float panY = 0.125; 
float zoomFactor = 0.01; 



using namespace std;

struct Image {                   // stores image data
   unsigned long sizeX;
   unsigned long sizeY;
   char *data;
};

void display(void)
{


    // Translation and Scaling
    glTranslatef(translateX, translateY, translateZ);
    glScalef(imgScale, imgScale, 0.0);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);


void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
   switch (key) {
      case 27:
         exit(0);
         break;
      case 'x':
        imgScale += zoomFactor;
        glutPostRedisplay();
         break;
      case 'z':
            imgScale -= zoomFactor;
            glutPostRedisplay();
         break;
      case 'w':
         translateY += panY;
         glutPostRedisplay();
         break;
      case 's':
         translateY -= panY;
         glutPostRedisplay();
         break;
      case 'a':
         translateX -= panX;
         glutPostRedisplay();
         break;
      case 'd':
         translateX += panX;
         glutPostRedisplay();
         break;
      default:
         break;
   }
}

void IdleFunc(void) {
    if (accepted != 1)
    {

      unsigned i;

      // Let all the devices do their things
      for (i = 0; i < num_devices; i++) {

      device_list[i].ana->mainloop();
      //cerr << i;
      }

    //  printf("Idle function test ");

    } 
    glutPostRedisplay();
}


//Callback handlers

void    VRPN_CALLBACK handle_analog (void *userdata, const vrpn_ANALOGCB a)
{
    int i;
    const char *name = (const char *)userdata;


    printf("Input from %s:\n  \n        %5.0f", name, a.channel[0]);
    for (i = 1; i < a.num_channel; i++) {
    printf(" %5.0f \n", a.channel[1]);
    }

    printf(" \n");
}













 // main interactive loop

  printf("Press ^C to exit.\n");
  while ( ! done ) {
#ifdef USE_TOMS_OGL
      glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(400,300);
    glutInitWindowPosition(200,100);
    glutCreateWindow("ImageViewer");


    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutIdleFunc(IdleFunc);
    glutMainLoop();
#else
      unsigned i;

      // Let all the devices do their things
      for (i = 0; i < num_devices; i++) {

      device_list[i].ana->mainloop();
      //cerr << i;
      }
      //cerr << endl;
#endif

  }
 return 0;
}  


// a.channel[0] =  x
// a.channel[1] =  y
// a.channel[2] =  Zoom
```

Comment: As requested the code has been added.

Comment: a.channel[0] =  x
a.channel[1] =  y
a.channel[2] =  Zoom

Comment: @TomLumbardܤ Could you condense the code to relevant sections?

Comment: Yes i have removed what i think to be unessary code for what im asking. Am i right in saying the 'a.channel[*]' needs to be made global somehow so i can add it to my panX or panY somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. Ive added this code ..

```
// Translate image on screen using data from device    

    yVal = a.channel[1];
    yVal = yVal/10000;
    translateY -= yVal;

    xVal = a.channel[0];

if (xVal >0 & xVal<250){

  xVal = xVal - 300;

}        

    xVal = xVal/15000;
    translateX += xVal;
```

xVal and Yval are divided to scale to the screen im using.

Comment: if you solved it, then you should accept this answer, even if it is your own.